# mypy overload and contextmanager

Tags: python, mypy

I am trying to implement an abstract & concrete class for a file opener.

However, with mypy (v0.910 on Python 3.8) I can't seem to get the typing working.
Below is my current code, and the error messages from mypy.

I also tried a few other "combinations" like `@contextmanager` on the abstract class, but just can't seem to find the right alchemy.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import ContextManager, Iterator, Literal, Union, overload


class Reader:
    """A file reader."""
    def __init__(self, path: str) -> None:
        self.path = path


class Writer:
    """A file writer."""
    def __init__(self, path: str) -> None:
        self.path = path


class FileOpenerAbstract(ABC):

    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def open(self,
             path: str,
             mode: Literal['r']
    ) -> ContextManager[Reader]:
        ...

    @overload
    @abstractmethod
    def open(self,
             path: str,
             mode: Literal['x', 'w', 'a']
    ) -> ContextManager[Writer]:
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def open(
        self,
        path: str,
        mode: Literal['r', 'x', 'w', 'a'] = 'r'
    ) -> Union[ContextManager[Reader], ContextManager[Writer]]:
        """Open an archive"""


class FileOpener(FileOpenerAbstract):

    @overload
    @contextmanager
    def open(self,
             path: str,
             mode: Literal['r']
    ) -> Iterator[Reader]:
        ...

    @overload
    @contextmanager
    def open(self,
             path: str,
             mode: Literal['x', 'w', 'a']
    ) -> Iterator[Writer]:
        ...

    @contextmanager
    def open(
        self,
        path: str,
        mode: Literal['r', 'x', 'w', 'a'] = 'r',
    ) -> Union[Iterator[Reader], Iterator[Writer]]:
        if mode == 'r':
            yield Reader(path)
        else:
            yield Writer(path)
```

```
$ mypy mypy_test.py
mypy_test.py:47: error: Signature of "open" incompatible with supertype "FileOpenerAbstract"
mypy_test.py:63: error: Overloaded function implementation cannot produce return type of signature 1
mypy_test.py:63: error: Overloaded function implementation cannot produce return type of signature 2
mypy_test.py:64: error: Signature of "open" incompatible with supertype "FileOpenerAbstract"
Found 4 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

any pointers on how to get this to work?

(note autocompletion with VS Code's Pylance, seems to work with this code, so I'm not sure if it is a limitation of mypy? But then again pylint also has issues with interpreting it)

Comment: are your return types matching?

Comment: There'a bug in current mypy version that might affect you https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11373